# Pandas: getting list of columns where max value == N

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, max

I know this way works, but is there a more standard way of doing this?

```
N=1
cols = list(data.iloc[:,(data.max()==1).values].columns)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,-1],'b':[3,4]})
df.columns[df.max()==1].tolist()
```

This prints `['a']`

Comment: Thanks much cleaner than mine. I'll accept this answer when it allows :)